# Can I ask question related to Aryan Invasion, Dowry, Sati and other off Topics?

Tags: discussion, scope

Currently the way Hindiusm is seen, these topics are considered as a part.

**Aryan Invasion** : We have related text about Aryans but none of them depict anything related to Invasion, making Aryan Invasion a off topic, but to sincere note, this is still a healthy part of discussion in many societies which consider it as a part of Hinduism.

**Dowry** : Again there is no written text about dowry in the text books, it was just a  surprise parents used to offer their girl child, which became a fellowship and converted to dowry again a non legitimate off topic discussion.

**Sati** : We have textures about *Devi Sati*, but nothing about *Sati practice*, again a off topic, yet a part of discussion in most societies.

Similarly their are numerous topics even caste system, which being not the part of Hinduism are attached to it, either by non-hindus, anti-hindus and some pro-hindus too.

Currently I see two division of Hinduism, a hinduism which acutally existed in the form of Sanatan Dharma pure and eternal, and Hinduism added by some blind-scholars, pride-prejudicers and stupid-fellowshipers.

As due to those empty vessels piled up, I think these can only be removed by conciousness. Can I add question relate to these and similar topics?

Comment: as a side note, Aryan invasion theory has been debunked by historians and experts. It was not backed by any scientific facts

Comment: @PratikBhat, if you go through Wikipedia, you will find context written in support of Aryan Invasion, this creates dogma in minds, and keeps the discussion going on for normal people.